# When to use Decimal.Round() instead of Math.Round()?

Tags: c#

I notice that [Math.Round()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Math.Round%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is more flexible than [Decimal.Round()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Decimal.Round%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), since it is able to handle everything that `Decimal.Round()` can, but also can do the same given `double` inputs. So is there any situation where using `Decimal.Round()` is better, or is using `Math.Round()` all the time a better idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the .NET source code: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/math.cs,4f39179a0098ab01

`Decimal Math::Round(Decimal)` is defined as a direct call to `Decimal Decimal::Round(Decimal)` so the two are semantic analogues.

I suppose by default I'd use `Decimal::Round` to avoid an extra function call, but the JIT should optimize that away anyway, so I'd probably use `Math::Round` to be consistent with other `Math` calls, if there were any, in the same code file.